# how to submit sj:autocompleter along with s:form

Tags: jquery, struts2

```
<s:form action="searchflight" method="post" id="flightform">
                    <s:url id="remoteurl" action="fromautofill"/>
                    <sj:autocompleter id="listFrom" name="from"
                                      label="From" parentTheme="xhtml"
                                      href="%{remoteurl}"
                                      delay="50" size="60"
                                      loadMinimumCount="2"
                                      onCompleteTopics="updateFrom"
                                      onSelectTopics="updateFrom"
                                      />
         <s:submit></s:form>
```

How to submit the value selected in the autocompleter along with form submission on clicking submit button.

I tried but always getting from(autocompleter name) value blank in the action.

Comment: See what is being sent to the server with firebug. It is much clearer to use jquery directly without that tag library obscuring things.

Comment: Well it looks fine. Do you have setter for "from"? or exclusives in your struts.xml ? Another case might be its value is not correct type, and validation is removing it. If none of these are the case, there might be something wrong with your javascript function "updateFrom". BTW, you can get what is written inside autocompleter by declaring String named "term" in action.

Comment: Do you see the populated list in the autocompleter.

Comment: Yes, I see populated list. I haven't applied any validation right now. I checked with firebug and chrome developer tools but nothing is being sent.

Comment: @batbaatar Yes I have a setter for "from" variable.
I haven't applied any validation yet.
Naming it as "term" won't work in case I've got two autocompleters in my form. "term" is only good for figuring out the suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I've figured out an alternative.

I have added hidden field and populated in on onSelectTopics of autocompleter as stated below :

```
<s:form action="searchflight" method="post" id="flightform">
<s:hidden name="from"/>                    
                    <sj:autocompleter id="listFrom"
                                      label="From" parentTheme="xhtml"
                                      href="%{remoteurl}"
                                      delay="50" size="60"
                                      loadMinimumCount="2"                                      
                                      onSelectTopics="updateFrom"
                                      />
 <s:submit></s:form>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $.subscribe('updateFrom', function(event,data) {
                document.flightform.from.value=event.originalEvent.ui.item.value;
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<sj:autocompleter id="listFrom"
                                 name="from"

                                 label="From" parentTheme="xhtml"
                                  href="%{remoteurl}"
                                  delay="50" size="60"
                                  loadMinimumCount="2"                                      
                                  onSelectTopics="updateFrom"
                                  />
```

> Notice if you are using name inside the autocompleter tag it will be
>   directly mapped to the getter in your model. So use the name attribute
>   instead of using hidden tag.
>
> Rest is ok.

Comment: I tried using that, but it doesn't work. I checked it in even in firebug and chrome dev tools the value of that autocompleter actually rendered as an input remains blank.

Comment: have you used header key and header value attributes and list attribute as well?

Comment: Using the list attribute will turn into a local list as far as I remember, and I need an ajax update, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes you are wrong in this case using proper getter/setter methods you can achieve data from database. And you should use list in this case to get the desired solution. Show me the `bean` and `action classes`.